# Change from .apply() to a function that uses list comprehension to compare one dataframe with a column of lists to values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, list-comprehension

Simply put, I want to change the following code into a funtion that doesn't use `apply` or `progress_apply`, so that the performance doesn't take 4+ hours to execute on 20 million+ rows.

```
d2['B'] = d2['C'].progress_apply(lambda x: [z for y in d1['B'] for z in y if x.startswith(z)])
d2['B'] = d2['B'].progress_apply(max)
```

**Full question below:**

I have two dataframes. The first dataframe has a column with 4 categories (A,B,C,D) with four different lists of numbers that I want to compare against a column in the second dataframe, which is not a list like in the first dataframe but instead just a single value that will start with one or more values from the first dataframe. As such, after executing some list comprehension to return a list of matching values in a new column in the second dataframe, the final step is to get the max of those values per list per row:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
               'B' : [['84'], ['8420', '8421', '8422', '8423', '8424', '8425', '8426'], ['847', '8475'], ['8470', '8471']]})

    A   B
0   A   [84]
1   B   [8420, 8421, 8422, 8423, 8424, 8425, 8426]
2   C   [847, 8475]
3   D   [8470, 8471]

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [8420513, 8421513, 8426513, 8427513, 8470513, 8470000, 8475000]})

    C
0   8420513
1   8421513
2   8426513
3   8427513
4   8470513
5   8470000
6   8475000
```

My current code is this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook
tqdm_notebook().pandas()
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'B' : [['84'], ['8420', '8421', '8422', '8423', '8424', '8425', '8426'], ['847', '8475'], ['8470', '8471']]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [8420513, 8421513, 8426513, 8427513, 8470513, 8470000, 8475000]})
d2['C'] = d2['C'].astype(str)
d2['B'] = d2['C'].progress_apply(lambda x: [z for y in d1['B'] for z in y if x.startswith(z)])
d2['B'] = d2['B'].progress_apply(max)
d2
```

and successfully returns this output:

```
    C       B
0   8420513 8420
1   8421513 8421
2   8426513 8426
3   8427513 84
4   8470513 8470
5   8470000 8470
6   8475000 8475
```

The problem lies with the fact that the `tqdm` progress bar is estimating the code will take **4-5 hours** to  run on my actual DataFrame with 20 million plus rows. I know that `.apply` should be avoided and that a custom function can be much faster, so that I don't have to go row-by-row. I can usually change `apply` to a function, but I am struggling with this particular one. I think I am far away, but I will share what I have tried:

```
def func1(df, d2C, d1B):
    return df[[z for y in d1B for z in y if z in d2C]]


d2['B'] = func1(d2, d2['C'], d1['B'])
d2
```

With this code, I am receiving `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1` and also still need to include code to get the max of each list per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try, using `explode` and regex with `extract`:

```
d1e = d1['B'].explode()
regstr = '('+'|'.join(sorted(d1e)[::-1])+')'
d2['B'] = d2['C'].astype('str').str.extract(regstr)
```

Output:

```
         C     B
0  8420513  8420
1  8421513  8421
2  8426513  8426
3  8427513    84
4  8470513  8470
5  8470000  8470
6  8475000  8475
```

Since, .str access is slower than list comprehension

```
import re
regstr = '|'.join(sorted(d1e)[::-1])
d2['B'] = [re.match(regstr, i).group() for i in d2['C'].astype('str')]
```

#### Timings:

```
from timeit import timeit
import re

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'B' : [['84'], ['8420', '8421', '8422', '8423', '8424', '8425', '8426'], ['847', '8475'], ['8470', '8471']]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [8420513, 8421513, 8426513, 8427513, 8470513, 8470000, 8475000]})
d2['C'] = d2['C'].astype(str)


def orig(d):
    d['B'] = d['C'].apply(lambda x: [z for y in d1['B'] for z in y if x.startswith(z)])
    d['B'] = d['B'].apply(max)
    return d
    
def comtorecords(d):
    d['B']=[max([z for y in d1.B for z in y if str(row[1]) .startswith(z)]) for row in d.to_records()]
    return d

def regxstracc(d):
    d1e = d1['B'].explode()
    regstr = '('+'|'.join(sorted(d1e)[::-1])+')'
    d['B'] = d['C'].astype('str').str.extract(regstr)
    return d

def regxcompre(d):
    regstr = '|'.join(sorted(d1e)[::-1])
    d['B'] = [re.match(regstr, i).group() for i in d['C'].astype('str')]
    return d


res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    columns='orig comtorecords regxstracc regxcompre'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([d2]*i)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        print(stmt, d.shape)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)

# res.groupby(res.columns.str[4:-1], axis=1).plot(loglog=True);
res.plot(loglog=True);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice and fastest approach +1 :)!  And idk why, but when I tested with the sample OP gave, the fastest was the  list comprehension, but with 7k rows of data, it was faster your first method. I'd think the comprehension list would be the quickest solution in this case, but it wasn't with more rows of data. At least on my computer...

Answer (score 3):

I have found yet faster solution, compared to both propositions of *Scott*.

```
def vect(d):
    def extr(txt):
        mtch = pat.match(txt)
        return mtch.group() if mtch else ''
    d1e = d1.B.explode()
    pat = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(d1e)[::-1]))
    d['B'] = np.vectorize(extr)(d.C)
    return d
```

One speed gain is from prior compilation of the regex.

The second gain is due to use of a *Numpy* vectorization, instead of
a list comprehension.

Running a testing loop like the one employed by *Scott*, I received
the following result:

[image]

So "my" execution time (the red line), especially for larger data volumes,
is about 60 % of both *regxstracc* and *regxcompre*.

Answer (score 2):

Try `explode` the d1 so we reduce one for loop

```
[max([z for z in d1.B.explode() if  x.startswith(z)]) for x in d2.C.astype(str) ]

['8420', '8421', '8426', '84', '8470', '8470', '8475']
```

Comment: This is a great one-liner @YORBEN_S . Thank youl

Answer (score 0):

Using re.compile() to compile the pattern *prior* to execution (i.e. outside of the ‘loop’) helps a lot when solving these big data row-by-row ‘requires a custom solution that isn’t a NumPy vector function already‘ problems.

Using the correct flags when compiling a pattern is work checking too.

Not to sound like a broken record but with NLP/text processing it’s definitely significant.

Another suggestion: Also use efficient chunking.

Each computing project has some X memory threshold and some Y processing threshold; balancing these by chunking helps improve execution speed.

Pandas chunking with its read/write functions are useful from my experience.

Finally, if you are executing I/O operations you might squeeze out some extra performance mapping the function within a ThreadPoolExecutor (A quick google can give you some good template code, and the documentation explains the utility well; I found the template code from documentation hard to implement at first so I’d check other resources).

Best of luck!